# Java libXt.so Unsatisfied Link error

Tags: uml

I am trying to install "Together UML tool" on my ubuntu 16.04. But it is giving me following error

```
mukund@mukund-Lenovo-U41-70:~/Downloads$ ./ta_4244v2_linux.bin
Preparing to install...
Extracting the JRE from the installer archive...
Unpacking the JRE...
Extracting the installation resources from the installer archive...
Configuring the installer for this system's environment...

Launching installer...

Invocation of this Java Application has caused an InvocationTargetException. This application will now exit. (LAX)

Stack Trace:
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: /tmp/install.dir.17310/Linux/resource/jre/jre/lib/i386/libawt.so: libXt.so.6: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
    at java.lang.ClassLoader$NativeLibrary.load(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary0(ClassLoader.java:1560)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(ClassLoader.java:1477)
    at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Runtime.java:788)
    at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:834)
    at sun.security.action.LoadLibraryAction.run(LoadLibraryAction.java:50)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at sun.awt.NativeLibLoader.loadLibraries(NativeLibLoader.java:38)
    at sun.awt.DebugHelper.<clinit>(DebugHelper.java:29)
    at java.awt.Component.<clinit>(Component.java:506)
    at com.zerog.ia.installer.Main.c(Unknown Source)
    at com.zerog.ia.installer.Main.main(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:324)
    at com.zerog.lax.LAX.launch(Unknown Source)
    at com.zerog.lax.LAX.main(Unknown Source)
GUI-
mukund@mukund-Lenovo-U41-70:~/Downloads$
```

Please help.

Comment: What Java have you installed?

Comment: mukund@mukund-Lenovo-U41-70:~/Downloads$ java -version
openjdk version "1.8.0_91"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_91-8u91-b14-3ubuntu1~16.04.1-b14)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.91-b14, mixed mode)

Answer (score 1):

Install libxt6 with

```
sudo apt-get install libxt6
```

Then check again

```
sudo updatedb
locate libXt.so.6
```

If you have libXt.so.6.0.0 and not libXt.so.6 go to the directory where you have the file and type

```
ln -s libXt.so.6.0.0 libXt.so.6
```

If you are on x86 architecture and would like to install i386 version type

```
sudo apt-get install libxt6:i386
```

Comment: I tried to install libxt6. 
It gives following

Comment: i have 64 bit architecture.
Both libXp and libXt are of latest version.

Comment: I have 64 bit architecture. And system has both 6.0.0 and 6 files. Now it is showing same error but for libXp.so.6. Although i have 6.0.2 and 6 files in system

Comment: You say you have libXp.so.6. What does command `locate libXp.so.6` return? It is unlikely but possible that the files are not in the right directories. Have you tried `sudo apt-get install libxp6`?

Comment: Try `sudo ldconfig -v | grep libXp.so.6` and see if library is in the path accessible to programs.

Comment: sudo ldconfig -v | grep libXp.so.6
sbin/ldconfig.real:Can't stat /lib/i686-linux-gnu: No such file or directry
sbin/ldconfig.real:Can't stat /usr/lib/i686-linux-gnu: No such file or directry
sbin/ldconfig.real:Path`/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu' given more than once
sbin/ldconfig.real:Path`/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu' given more than once
sbin/ldconfig.real:/lib/i386-linux-gnu/ld-2.23.so is the dynamic linker, ignoring
sbin/ldconfig.real:/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ld-2.23.so is the dynamic linker, ignoring
libXp.so.6->libXp.so.6.2.0
sbin/ldconfig.real:/lib32/ld-2.23.so is the dynamic linker, ignoring

Comment: I am getting the above response to sudo ldconfig -v | grep libXp.so.6

Comment: The line `libXp.so.6->libXp.so.6.2.0` says that you have the libXp.so.6 installed properly. Are you sure that the program now reports missing libXp.so.6?

Comment: Yes it still gives the error. If i install earlier version of libXp it gives error for libXt.so.6. If i install updated version of libXp it gives error for libXp.so.6

Comment: That is strange. What about the latest versions of both libraries? Have you tried just `sudo apt-get upgrade` to make sure the versions will match. Then, if it still complains, try to make a symbolic link for the file it reports missing, like I suggested in the answer already.